# How to add column descriptions (comments) in Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to add a *column description* (also called a "*comment*") to a column defined by a Doctrine2 entity but can't find any information on how to do it using the `@Column annotation` without possibly breaking Doctrine's SchemaTool.

If I use the `columnDefinition` attribute of the `@Column annotation` like

```
@Column(type="string" columnDefinition="COMMENT 'This is a column comment'")
```

the [annotations reference](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column) states

> SchemaTool will not detect changes on the column correctly anymore if you use “columnDefinition”.

So is there a way to define a column description without breaking the SchemaTool?

The only clue I got was [this pull request](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/217) which ended in "*This was solved in different ways.*".

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can add a comment to a column name or entire table with the "options" argument to the annotation; eg:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", options={"comment":"The string to show in the dropdown "})
 */
```

for a column, or for a table:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="application", options={"comment":"Funding applications"});
 */
```

Note however this will not add comments to an existing table or column, you have to delete the table from the DB and rebuild it. If it's just adding comments, you could rename the table, create the new table, and import data from the original.

Source: [Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column)

Comment: Perfect, thank you! As we are in development right now it's no problem to rebuild the database. Where did you find this? I dug through the whole code I thought...

Comment: Keep in mind that your comment will be added to the SQL-statement as is (without escaping), thus if you use apostrophes in the comment, be sure to escape them. eg. `options={"comment"="The string to show in dropdown with default value \'none selected\'"}`

Comment: What about relations? How to add comment to a column in a relation?

Comment: @Victor See [this example from the Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/yaml-mapping.html#example) to see how to add `comments` to `yml mapping` files.

Comment: Here is the new link.  Edit queue was full.  https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_column

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 6, Now I tried it like that.

#[ORM\Column(length: 55, nullable: true, options:["comment"=>"Add your column comments here"])]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).