# symfony2 entity column comment or description

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to add table's Column comment or description using Symfony2 Entity,

I also tried the below link, but could not succeed :-
[How to add column descriptions (comments) in Doctrine2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933384/how-to-add-column-descriptions-comments-in-doctrine2)

Comment: did your table / field exist ou it's for an update ?

Comment: Table exist and i also change/update entity as per the requirement.

Comment: what say `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` cmd ?

Comment: try that, is good but issue is that when we update our current entity it does not update, we need to do it manually..

Comment: the question is : did you have the sql instriction for your comment in the dump ?

Comment: yes, i got the sql instruction in the dump

Comment: so tou should execute it `doctrine:schema:update --force` you should exute an update command. Symfony & Doctrine don't detect change by them self sory.

Comment: ok, that means it's bit difficult to give comment to a column in Symfony 2, Doctrine2

Comment: sorry but every Database update need an execution. And add comment is an update. Why is so difficult ? an update dont loose associated data you know ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/**
 * @var string $description
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
protected $description = "";
```