# How to add comment for table in yaml mapping format with Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, comments, yaml

I need to add comment for whole table, not only for column, How can I do it with `yml` mapping format. I try next definition:

```
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: users
    comment: 'Users table'
    options:
        comment: 'Users table'
```

But it not work for table comment.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13823167/1423650) answer.

Comment: @StivenLlupa Thanks, it's look like well but used `annotation`. I need the same but for `yaml` format.

Comment: They are basically the same, just follow the same 'pattern' and 'depth'. Give it a try

Comment: @StivenLlupa I update my question. It's still not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the annotations reference, it says only the column has an options attribute for comments. And that too is vendor specific. You need to check if your db supports it.

Check: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column

Comment: I use MySQL database that support comments for tables

Comment: Looks like you can have only comments for columns not the table.

Comment: Look at [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) syntax. I can comment tables

Comment: Yes, but what I meant was doctrine does not have a way to add it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include the `coments` section within the `options` section at the table label. Given example:

```
Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: users
    options:
        comment: 'Table comment'
    fields:
        field1:
            type: field_type
            nullable: [true|false]
            options:
                comment: 'Field comment'
            column: table_column
```

Be careful with indentations.

Tested with Symfony 2.6.6, Doctrine 2.5.4

Comment: Hey, thanks! Is it work for MySQL? Which DB server did you test?

Comment: Affirmative, MySQL 5.5