# How to add column descriptions/comments in Symfony Doctrine 2.11

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony6

I want to add column description or comment in the below line but i am getting error.

#[ORM\Column(length: 100, nullable: true)]

So if you have any idea then please suggest me?

I am trying to below line but it's not working please suggest me right way to add this:

#[ORM\Column(length: 100, nullable: true, columnDefinition: 'Test only')]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933384/how-to-add-column-descriptions-comments-in-doctrine2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add column descriptions (comments) in Doctrine2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933384/how-to-add-column-descriptions-comments-in-doctrine2)

Comment: Actually, structuring issue in Symfony 6, Now I tried it like that.

#[ORM\Column(length: 55, nullable: true, options:["comment"=>"Add your column comments here"])]